# Three proportional views autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have three views I want to divide in a `superview`.
Currently, when I set `proportional heights`, I get weird results when updating the `multiplier` in those constraints.

[image: first view]

As you can see, there is weird `space` between the `top` and the `first` `proportional view` and the `second`.
I want no room in between.

[image: second view]
[image: third view]
[image: fourth view]

Who can help me out?

Comment: Try changing the background color of your top view. I think there is an issue with your image.

Comment: whats the image fill mode?

Comment: Aspect fill is the image fill mode

Answer (score 1):

Two things immediately

1. It would be simpler to set the proportional height in this case between each of the views and their superview. This may not be what you want but either way my example below would work with slight tweaking
2. You only need to set two of the views to have proportional height. The third view (the one in the middle) can just take up the remaining space in between them.

[image: Finished Article]

See the Red, Green and Blue views -

- The red view hugs the top, left and right and has a proportional
  height
- The green view hugs the bottom, left and right and has a proportional
  height
- The blue view hugs the left and right and has vertical spacing (zero)
  to the red view and vertical spacing (zero) to the green view.

[image: Red]

[image: Green]

[image: Blue]